# Using SessionState mode=SQLServer like cookies

Tags: session, session-state, session-cookies

I am trying to persist settings on a page through browser close/re-open. Currently the page has no concept of a user logging in. Every time I close the browser, re-open the browser, and load the page a new SessionID is created. I would like to load the old SessionID. Is this possible? I'd assume so since that's the entire point of saving it, but after Googling for a bit I didn't see anything on this.

I tried setting the timeout to a year, but even with a high timeout it still creates a new SessionID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [persistent cookies](http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/cookies-the-same.html). In ASP.NET when you emit a cookie you could set the [`Expires`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.expires.aspx) property to some date into the future. This will create a persistent cookie on the client browser and you will be able to fetch the value back even if the user closes/reopens the browser again.

And because we live in 2011 and HTML5 is knocking on our doors (it has even entered inside some homes) it is worth looking into the [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Comment: Well, I'm working with a bit of a time constraint right now. Ideally I'd be able to just log in as a mock guest-user and have the solution I've currently implemented be able to restore Session based on the user (even though it will always be Guest)

Comment: @Sean Anderson, in ASP.NET session is tracked with cookies. Authentication also. So you need persistent cookies if you want persistent sessions/forms authentication tickets.

Comment: I am confused. Why would cookies help my current issue? The only thing I would use a cookie for is to persist a SessionID, but I can just hardcode a value for that. I just don't see where I would be able to provide this SessionID to Session so that it uses the right properties it has serialized and written to SQL DB.